# CLI creating a paper wallet

Tags: wallet

Is a paper wallet the same as doing.

```
$ cardano-wallet recovery-phrase generate > recovery-phrase.txt
$ cardano-wallet wallet from-recovery-phrase
$ cardano-wallet address list | grep_first_unused.sh | QR_code_generator.sh > wallet_qr.png
$ print_to_paper.sh < wallet_qr.png
$ print_to_paper.sh < recovery-phrase.txt
```

Or is there more to it than that? I have heard people talk about it but could not find the feature in the latest Daedalus.

Paper wallet as discussed by Charles here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JwhB2YKYFKs&t=1s

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "paper wallet". If you want to generate a 24 word mnemonic in secure, ultra-cold fashion, you'd need to use cardano-cli in conjunction with cardano-wallet on an airgapped machine.

If however you do not require something as sexy as a 24 word mnemonic, you can just use `cardano-cli address key-gen` on an airgapped machine and write down the cborHex of the skey on paper.

Comment: Ok yeah I just tried the commands air-gapped. Works like normal, interesting. So you could share an airgapped address with somebody and it will just work? 

Oh I changed the command from address create to address list.

Comment: Yes, when you key-gen on an airgapped machine, whatever addresses you then build using the created vkey can be accessed/authorized with the associated skey.